# Quote on other cultures from Greek scholar

Tags: classical-antiquity, anthropology, greek

I can remember from my Greek / Latin classes that a scholar from antiquity once wrote that

> *to write about another culture shows more about the writer himself than about the other culture*

However, I cannot find the correct phrasing or the author of this quote. I think it might have been Herodotus but I have no source for it. Does anyone know the author, the correct phrasing and which book/work it comes from?

Comment: Searching "The Histories" from Herodotus in the Perseus site did not reveal anything. You can try here: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/search?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D1%3Asection%3D0

Comment: Sounds very Greek

Comment: I do not know about Greeks, but in Spanish there is a proverb that says "What Diego is telling about Pablo tells more about Diego than it tells about Pablo" ("Lo que Diego dice de Pablo dice más de Diego que de Pablo"). This approach has also been used by some travel and epistolary literature, using the comparation with other cultures to reflect -and criticize- about the author own culture (e.g., "Gulliver's Travels").